# JVectormap set in hover state from a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, jvectormap

i have done a custom map with [JVectormap](http://jvectormap.com/) and added a links-list with the same states in another div on the same page.

```
<div id="mylinks">
    <a href="#" id="state1" >State1</a>
    <a href="#" id="state2" >State2</a>
    <a href="#" id="state3" >State3</a>
</div>
```

When i mouseover the links i want to activate the hoverstate on the map. How can i tell jvectormap from outside to activate a state ?

```
$('a').mouseover(function (e) {
  var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
  switch (id){
    case "state1":
    // Set State1 in Hovermode
    break;
    .
    .
    . 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Get reference to the map object

```
map = $("#world-map-gdp").vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
```

Use this method

```
map.setSelectedRegions(['IT']);
```

In my case hover Italy

I'm not sure if this exists in all maps types, but in world exist and work.